# JxBrowser - dispose but there's still BrowserCore processes in Task Manager

Tags: jxbrowser

In my application, when running JxBrowser for a long time, it consumes so huge RAM, so I decide to dispose & re-create another instance for Browser. But when dispose, sometimes the BrowserCore processes are not terminated. Is is a bug or disposing browser cannot guarantee that it kills the BrowserCore process?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that the render process will be terminated. It can be held for example by the popup browser window. Chromium engine decides when to terminate browser process.

Still, it is guaranteed that BrowserCore processes would be terminated in case all the Browser instances are terminated.

Comment: In above case, even if I close my application, the BrowserCore processes still exist. Is there any way to terminate them?

Comment: Try calling Browser.dispose() method for each browser instance running

Comment: I mean when I dispose & exit app, the BrowserCore processes still exist

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `Browser.dispose()`, and it doesn't work.

Only `Engine.close()` will destroy all "BrowserCore Chromium Native Process" for the engine you have created. **I wonder** if there is way to recycle all Chromium Native Process. Since every creation of engine is costly and slow, if I use single engine for this app, every time I open a browser and it will create a Chromium Native Process which will not be killed with Browser.dispose() alone.

Answer (score 0):

I have to manually dispose the created browser and create a new one. But sometimes, the dispose method does not work, I need to iterate all the existing browsers and kill them all:

```
  import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC;  

  IPC.getBrowsers().forEach(Browser::dispose);
```

Comment: What does IPC stand for?

Comment: Thanks for providing package source, but in my case with JxBrowser 7.5, `com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.` isn't available anymore. What JxBrowser version are you using?

Comment: @leoflower: ah, we don’t use jxbrowser anymore so I forgot that its version is 7.x now. Let me take a look